# Can I install Kali tools on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, security, software-sources

I want to know if there is any way to install Kali tools like `sqlmap`, `nikto`, `john`, `aircrack-ng`, ... on Ubuntu 12.04?

If yes, then how should I proceed?

Comment: Yes, they are all in the debian repositories, which both distro's share (for the most part). Otherwise you can download a .deb, and use `dpkg -i`

Comment: **Can anybody update this question with a new answer providing current repositories? Thank you!**

Comment: @Adnan Ali Error about 'unknown armor header' maybe some blank space at the head of Version: SKS 1.1.4, just delete them

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## The only current version of Ubuntu this works for is 12.04 and the repos haven't been updated since 2013. Don't use it.

## For 14.04+, please see [the second answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/653758/449).

---

#### Copy the following Kali repositories:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wagungs/kali-linux2/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/wagungs/kali-linux2/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION         main 
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wagungs/kali-linux/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/wagungs/kali-linux/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION main
```

Replace the text `YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION` based on your Ubuntu version.

- Ubuntu 12.04: `precise`
- Ubuntu 12.10: `quantal`
- Ubuntu 13.04: `raring`

Assuming that you are using Ubuntu 13.04, your repositories would be

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wagungs/kali-linux2/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/wagungs/kali-linux2/ubuntu raring main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wagungs/kali-linux/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/wagungs/kali-linux/ubuntu raring main
```

Note: If you're an Ubuntu 14.04 user, you can use `raring`, as Trusty version of Kali repositories are not released

#### Update sources

Open your sources using the command

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali-tools.list
```

Now, gedit editor will open the file `kali-tools.list`. Paste the above code at the end of your file and Save.

#### Copy the PGP Key

Copy the Key below and save it as key.pgp text file in your desktop.

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
 Version: SKS 1.1.4
 Comment: Hostname: keyserver.ubuntu.com

 mI0ET324YwEEANbSlISrOlAGjxgFRxiN6jk0JIl/vxQ8lapRdxZ4DHDAQdXbX4AuigMBkP5e
 sOxhMpDnkgMRtEVpaBMdQheA0/431pPQYqkr3jdeZw5JS5opiyJ4qr/QrcoSFHSluEkWkbZ6
 RYOkA25vW31KK2FB2LQVRYk580llXAVgIUznm2ATABEBAAG0GExhdW5jaHBhZCBQUEEgZm9y
 IHdhZ3VuZ4i4BBMBAgAiBQJPfbhjAhsDBgsJCAcDAgYVCAIJCgsEFgIDAQIeAQIXgAAKCRAb
 IuuNj9/bVxabBADSGN8cp+hqkdZqwq263wdz/UGsiuB1bCrH06/HznC/ZC5rjfH3aQ1Dwwag
 zYCrSD3c0cKNAqD10009N76RMlzZBH8kKL9khH3zPL/k4/lYuVP7y6NKFbBsnawEUc0mWcCa
 mH4ScTdWWPXP/mOQiUUjnQ1bZhzpcbQOb+hEUAqExg==
 =fJ+8
 -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

#### Add PGP Key in apt

Open terminal and type

```
cd Desktop
sudo apt-key add key.pgp
```

If your key addition is successful, you will see `Ok`.

Now update your apt-get repositories using the command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

#### Install Synaptic Package Manager

Use the command

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

If you already have Synaptic installed, you may skip this step.

#### Install Kali Tools

Now open Synaptic Package manager and click on Origin. You can see 2 Kali repositories by names

```
LP-PPA-wagungs-kali-linux/raring
LP-PPA-wagungs-kali-linux2/raring
```

Click on the repositories and install the Tools from the list.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What about Utopic (14.10) and Vivid (15.04)? Still use the Raring repo? Or do they exist?

Comment: @ByteCommander: After fast check on http://ppa.launchpad.net/wagungs/kali-linux2/ubuntu, the answer is no, they doesn't exist. Only `raring` available.

Comment: @NNToan Can you tell whether they are usable for current Ubuntu versions or should one not even try to use those long outdated versions? I guess they're missing two years of updates then and are pretty deprecated to use today.

Comment: Its giving Error:
gpg: unknown armor header:  Version: SKS 1.1.4
gpg: unknown armor header:  Comment: Hostname: keyserver.ubuntu.com
OK

Comment: Comment taken from a NAA of Zhaosheng Qiu: *@Adnan Ali Error about 'unknown armor header' maybe some blank space at the head of Version: SKS 1.1.4, just delete them*

Answer (score 8):

Ubuntu has more than that I think!

- Cyber Sec I PPa's (Cybersec Team)
- Black hat sec PPA's ( by D4RkNiK0l4s)

**Utopic**

```
ppa:darklordpaunik8880/kalibuntu
ppa:darklordpaunik8880/kalibuntu1
```

**Trusty**

```
ppa:cybersec/chaos-ppa
ppa:cybersec/chaos-ppa-v1
ppa:cybersec/chaos-ppa-v2
ppa:cybersec/test
ppa:cybersec/trojan-horse
ppa:darklordpaunik8880/darkminttrustytahr
ppa:darklordpaunik8880/darkminttrustytahr2
ppa:darklordpaunik8880/darkminttrustytahr3
ppa:darklordpaunik8880/darkminttrustytahr4
```

In those PPa's are more than 500+ hacking tools available,
this guy has done a very good job!!Those tools are all open source and they don't belong to any name or something else. :D Ubuntu is a great distribution and it has many,many tools and packages available via repository
install them like this :

**Trusty**

```
sudo add-apt-repository  ppa:cybersec/chaos-ppa
sudo add-apt-repository  ppa:cybersec/chaos-ppa-v1
sudo add-apt-repository  ppa:cybersec/chaos-ppa-v2
sudo add-apt-repository  ppa:cybersec/test
sudo add-apt-repository  ppa:cybersec/trojan-horse
sudo add-apt-repository  ppa:darklordpaunik8880/darkminttrustytahr
sudo add-apt-repository  ppa:darklordpaunik8880/darkminttrustytahr2
sudo add-apt-repository  ppa:darklordpaunik8880/darkminttrustytahr3
sudo add-apt-repository  ppa:darklordpaunik8880/darkminttrustytahr4
```

**Utopic**

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:darklordpaunik8880/kalibuntu                  
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:darklordpaunik8880/kalibuntu1
```

Then open synaptic or  whatever you like to use and start installing your tools!!

Answer (score 1):

first of all , i dont advice you to change anything in the sources.list , because it going to damage your ubuntu sooner or later.

but there is a good way to do so in these instructs :
there is a good tool called katoolin that will save time for you.

**warning: make a copy of your sources list**

step 1 : copy your original sources.list

`sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.original`

step 2: install git

`sudo apt-get install git`

step 3: get katoolin tool

`git clone https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin.git`

step 4 : copy the tool to your usr bin directory

`cp katoolin/katoolin.py /usr/bin/katoolin`

step 5 : change permissions to the tool

`sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/katoolin`

step 6 : run the tool and extra careful to do a sources.list clean up after every time you install a tool from it or use the tool to remove the repos , and check your self manually.

`sudo katoolin`

**cleanup after running the tool**

***warning :*** dont use apt-get upgrade after running the tool it will crush your system and gnome

first of all see the changes that happened in your sources.list

step 1 : check what has been added

`cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep "kali"`

if you see a kali source , remove its deb and deb-src and the safe the file.

step 2 : check if there is any ppa from it and remove it :

`sudo apt-key list | grep kali`
`sudo apt-key del <id>`

step 3 : clean what you just did
:

`sudo apt-get autoremove && apt-get clean`

**useful references** :

([How can I remove gpg key that I added using apt-key add -?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107177/how-can-i-remove-gpg-key-that-i-added-using-apt-key-add))

best regards,

Comment: can you not just revert to the backup sources list?