# Find Kali Security tester tools after installation

Tags: security, tools, kali

I'm a 'beginner' with Ubuntu. I tried it already a few times. I also tried Kali, etc already. I think Ubuntu is very useful, and has many possiblities. But I missed one thing from Kali. The Security tester tools (Also known als Hacking tools). I installed them like discripted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558679/can-i-install-all-the-hacking-tools-of-kali-on-ubuntu), but I can't find the place they're located. It doesn't stand between my 'Toepassingen', it's called in Dutch.. I don't know the name in English, I think APPS. So my question is where i can find them on my Ubuntu PC. That is the missing link in the link below. Thanks!

Comment: Your link is outdated might have something to do with it. The most recent software source in the only answer to the linked question was for 13.04, and you are using what release -- 12.04?, 14.04?, 14.10?