# Proper Installation of Kali linux tools in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, kali, katoolin

I think everyone has known - we need to install `katoolin` to use Kali Linux Tools on Ubuntu. Before did anything I had looked through the internet and also found out these solutions: [Can I install Kali tools on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558679/can-i-install-kali-tools-on-ubuntu), [How to Auto Install All Kali Linux](http://www.tecmint.com/install-kali-linux-tools-using-katoolin-on-ubuntu-debian/)

So here are my steps:

```
apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin.git && cp katoolin/katoolin.py /usr/bin/katoolin
chmod +x  /usr/bin/katoolin
sudo katoolin
```

Then, to add Kali Linux repositories and update them, I selected option 1 from the `katoolin` Menu

Then, to view the available categories and install all available tools, I selected option 2 from the main menu of `katoolin` and then pressed 0.

But after that I got this:

[image: unable to locate package webshag]

```
What do you want to do ?>  

1) Add Kali repositories & Update 
2) View Categories
3) Install classicmenu indicator
4) Install Kali menu
5) Help


kat > 2

************************** All Categories **************************

1) Information Gathering                      8) Exploitation Tools
2) Vulnerability Analysis                     9) Forensics Tools
3) Wireless Attacks                           10) Stress Testing
4) Web Applications                           11) Password Attacks
5) Sniffing & Spoofing                        12) Reverse Engineering
6) Maintaining Access                         13) Hardware Hacking
7) Reporting Tools                            14) Extra

0) All


Select a category or press (0) to install all Kali linux tools .
```

Furthermore, I got an error in Software Updater - it didn't let me do anything. Ubuntu just hung up. I solved this problem by deleting kali linux repositories in `katoolin` and then in Software Updater.

Does anyone know how to install Kali Linux tools in Ubuntu 16.04 in a proper way?

Comment: I got past this part but had failures when trying to install all packages in categories with option 0. Now when I use 'sudo apt-get dist upgrade' I get the following error: http://pastebin.com/1cz6DjMD

Comment: Errors when using option 0 are as follows: http://pastebin.com/YQNqGs53

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Introduction

Katoolin is a collection of scripts for automating the installation of Kali linux tools in different platforms other than Kali linux, and installing Kali linux tools with Katoolin in other OSs or Windows Subsystem for Linux is always less secure than installing the same tools in Kali Linux. Kali Linux is named after the Hindu goddess of destruction which should give the user some indication that even Kali Linux itself is risky and difficult to manage, especially for new users.

Katoolin draws its tools from a variety of sources including apt and GitHub. Katoolin doesn't know anything about the platform that it is running on, so the safest way to use Katoolin is to install each tool the hard way one tool at a time, checking each time to see if that tool is included in the default Ubuntu repositories and if so installing it that way instead. When the installation is finished, the software sources that were added by Katoolin should be immediately disabled in order to prevent Katoolin from replacing packages that were installed from the default Ubuntu repositories with its own updated packages whenever Ubuntu software is updated.

---

### Installation of Kali linux tools

(Re)install Katoolin as follows:

1. Open the terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo apt install git  
   git clone https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin.git && sudo cp katoolin/katoolin.py /usr/bin/katoolin
   ```
2. Make `/usr/bin/katoolin` executable.

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/katoolin
   ```
3. Run Katoolin as follows and you will see the Katoolin interface:

   ```
   cd /usr/bin/
   sudo ./katoolin
   ```

   [image: enter imageterminal an description here]
   <sup>**View the categories of available software in katoolin interface**</sup>

> Press 0 to install all Kali linux tools.
>
> When you go to *View Categories* and then enter 0 for all, the installer will immediately return to where you were. Scroll up, and you'll see that a number of the packages can't be found. Those packages are no longer maintained or have been removed from the Kali repositories. Even with this issue, you'll still find a lot of the Kali software available for installation.
>
> So the best option is to install Kali linux tools in a series of distinct steps. Just like if you want to install Forensic tools on your system, then choose its option from the category and then type 0 to install all forensics tools. *If this still doesn't work, then you have to install whatever forensic tools that can be installed one package at a time.*
>
> *This is why the Katoolin interface sometimes hangs when you try to install all of the Kali linux tools at once. Take the time of waiting for the server to respond to a request for a package that is not available and multiply it by how many unavailable Kali linux tools there are in the Katoolin repositories.*
>
> [image]
>
> If you wish to go back to the main menu, type `gohome` in your katoolin interface. Now select the option 3 or 4 to install either the classicmenu indicator or the Kali menu. Press the <kbd>y</kbd> key to continue and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start its setup.
>
> Once you are done with installation of Kali tools using katoolin, you can quit by pressing the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and you will see the goodbye message.
>
> `shutdown requested....Goodbye...`

<sub>Credit for the above text block goes to Kashif at [How To Install Kali Linux Tools On Ubuntu 16 And CentOS 7](https://linuxpitstop.com/install-kali-linux-tools-on-ubuntu-and-centos/) with my additions italicized.</sub>

---

### Warning about updates after installing Kali linux tools

The [LionSec Katoolin GitHub](https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin) webpage clearly warns Katoolin users to be careful when updating software.

> Before updating your system, please remove all Kali-linux repositories to avoid any kind of problem.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But it's not clear how can I install one package at a time in case it is not downloaded via katoolin. I need to install it separately - am I right?And how can I do this?

Comment: If you press 0 on the Forensic tools screen katoolin tries to install all 23 forensic tools, but you can also press 1 to install only forensic tool 1, 2 to install only forensic tool 2, etc. by a process of divide and conquer. There are 330 Kali linux tools, so it's more time consuming to do everything one package at a time, but it's also less destabilizing to your operating system. It seems to me that Katoolin is giving hints to help me think like a hacker like when I lose my money in a soft drink vending machine, I have to kick the vending machine to break it for everyone else.

Comment: So I did the next steps: step1- sudo katoolin, step2- View Categories, step3 - сhoose 5-Sniffing & Spoofing, step4 - choose 20 and got the next `kat > 20          
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package sipp` . What should  I do next? Install `sipp` package on my own in ubuntu and then relaunch katoolin and chose this option again?

Comment: I searched for sipp manually and found it at [Ubuntu Packages Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/). The sipp program is provided by the sip-tester package from the default Ubuntu repositories. To install it in Ubuntu type: `sudo apt-get install sip-tester` Then sipp will be installed to `/usr/bin/sipp` I also downloaded another file called sipp-1d6c5d8.tar.gz from elsewhere in case you want to install that.

Comment: Dear karel, but if I repeat the steps mentioned in `my question` the issue will happen again. So it is very strange as for me to see  such behavior of katoolin. The summary of all you described above lead to the following conclusion: `1)` katoolin is not configured properly to interact with ubuntu 16.04 LTS `2)` if someone wants to use katoolin on ubuntu 16.04 LTS he/she has to  do it in a series of distinct steps `3)`if some package is missing it is needed to install it on your own in case you can find that package. Do I understand this right?

Comment: Yes you understand this right and I will add that ka**tool**in is a package management **tool** that is installed over the Ubuntu operating system and similar things happen in Ubuntu with other package management tools like pip, Enthought Canopy and npm. I don't think it's strange because I have accepted problems with this type of package management tool as a fact of life.

Comment: @Karel did you confirm this doesn't crash the system on 16.04? I had that problem with a fresh install of Ubuntu-GNOME. Can you confirm it doesn't crash 16.04?

Comment: You asked for a detailed Canonical answer to address all the concerns. I interpret that as rating all the Kali linux tools repositories and >300 Kali linux tools. Kali Linux is named after a goddess of death with between 4 and 18 arms. That means the Kali Linux developers won't tell you, just grab a lot of packages and install them and see for yourself. I don't have a better answer than they do. If I did have one I would think I deserved the bounty, otherwise I don't any more than Thom Yorke does. Have a nice day and I'll have one too if possible.

Comment: @Karel I'm giving you a bounty but I think you should put a note at the top that using this package can crash your system if that's what happens on standard Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 3):

After using `katoolin` and adding the repositories , its safe to run  `sudo apt-get update`, but **do not use `apt-get upgrade`** if you do, your `gnome` and desktop will fail to start.

In katoolin :

1. Add kali repositories & Update
2. Update your `apt-get` by katoolin or your terminal

Install all the tools you want, after that do the cleaning by removing kali repos from your `sources.list` and `apt-key`.

If any error occurs, it comes from the `sources.list`, meaning the package or tool is not designed/available for your Linux architecture or `katoolin` itself has to be updated, because repositories were changed by the owner.

**Advice:**

1. Keep in touch with katoolin developers.
2. Install `aptitude`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install aptitude
   ```

   then do a search for the requirements of the package candidates, for example:

   ```
   aptitude search "?provides(wine)"
   ```

   read more about `aptitude`: [What is the difference between dpkg and aptitude/apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309113/what-is-the-difference-between-dpkg-and-aptitude-apt-get)
3. Read about the difference between `unable to locate package` & `no candidates`: [What does Package <package> has no installation candidate mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14685/what-does-package-package-has-no-installation-candidate-mean)

There is a step by step solution that avoids crashes here: [Can I install Kali tools on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558679/can-i-install-kali-tools-on-ubuntu/825664#825664)

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 16: edit file `/usr/bin/katoolin` and remove all references for the both packages: `dff` and `webshag` and save file.

Execute `katoolin` again - choose `1` and then `2` to update - after that type `back` and choose `2` and then type `0`.

For me it still showed an error for `usb-modeswitch` for version `2.2.5+repack0-1ubuntu1`, so I installed using [this package from ubuntuupdates.org](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/xenial/main/base/usb-modeswitch)

After that I executed `katoolin` again - chose `1` and then `2` to update - after that type `back` and choose `2` and then `0` to begin installation.

Comment: Could you, please, clarify what those references exactly are? In the previous answer was the same like proposition, but it did not work.

Answer (score -2):

I have faced the very same
Edit the file `/usr/bin/katoolin` (eg use `sudo -H gedit usr/bin/katoolin`) and remove those two packages, just search for text `dff` and `webshag`. Remove those two from `apt-get` commands too.

Comment: Well, I did what you said, but this didn't work for me. Maybe some specific option or maybe more explanation from you can resolve the problem.