# After installing Kali tools with Katoolin in Ubuntu 16.04 cannot find any of the tools

Tags: katoolin

I just finished installing Kali tools via katoolin script in Ubuntu 16.04. I followed th instructions from here: [Proper Installation of Kali linux tools in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772495/proper-installation-of-kali-linux-tools-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts), but now I cannot see any of the tools as being installed. Can you help, please? Thank you.

Comment: Install Kali.... the mail tool repo is not easy to use and poorly supported here or by kali

Comment: Hello. The only problem is my second VGA card (NVidia GTX 770M). I had Kali installed as standalone, but when I tried to install nvidia drivers it stalled after restart. After that I read on Kali webpage that NVidia drivers are not quite supported. I cannot do password cracking with Intel VGA.

Comment: You can just manually install the applications you need, for instance you might need `hashcat`.

Comment: In katoolin after where it says: *What do you want to do?* did you install either option 3) *Install classic menu indicator* or option  4) *Install Kali menu* and then it didn't work? [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uxio.png)

Comment: Close voters: Please read this **Meta question** [Question about Katoolin is being close voted as off-topic because it's “not about Ubuntu”](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16212/question-about-katoolin-is-being-close-voted-as-off-topic-because-its-not-abou) before you incorrectly review this question and then it will need to be reopened.