# Can't use sudo and couldn't access root user to fix it after running chmod -R 777 /usr/

Tags: 16.04, permissions, sudo

I used these commands to allow access to git clone katoolin to be stored in `usr`

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/
sudo chown www-data:www-data /usr/
```

I don't know which one ruined my `sudo` access. Also, I don't have access to root. I tried entering into recovery mode then into root shell and used commands from [/usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set/471503#471503) but it didn't work.

Kind of new to it. Some help would be helpful.

Comment: Proper way to install Katoolin: https://askubuntu.com/questions/772495/proper-installation-of-kali-linux-tools-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/827323#827323

Answer (score 3):

`sudo chmod -R 777 /usr;sudo chown www-data:www-data /usr/` broke your system irretrievably. There are two methods of recovering from such an error. First, and by far the easiest, is to reinstall Ubuntu. The second is to find the correct ownerships and permissions of each of the approximately 542,574  files and directories in `/usr`, and change each file or directory to the correct value for each one.