# Can't locate sqlmap and also katoolin

Tags: command-line, system-installation

I tried to install katoolin on my Ubuntu OS on Virtual box, but I was unable to do so.. Please help me.

```
root@ubuntu:/home/hackman/Downloads/katoolin-master# apt-get install git clone github.com/LionSec/katoolin.git 
Reading package list . . . Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information . . . Done 
E: unable to locate package clone 
E: unable to locate package github.com/LionSec
E: couldn't find any package by regex 'github.com/LionSec
```

Comment: How did you try to install it?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question with the exact commands and sequence of commands you ran, and include any arrer messages you got?

Comment: Add the commands you ran by [edit]ing your post to preserve the formatting.

Comment: Press [edit] under your question (or the link I have provided several times labeled **edit**). Add the information I requested. Press save. Do not keep adding comments, please. Comments does not preserve formatting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper Installation of Kali linux tools in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772495/proper-installation-of-kali-linux-tools-in-ubuntu)

Comment: I tried it over and over again. It not working.. Karel