# Katoolin is giving a syntax error

Tags: command-line, 18.04, bash, katoolin

I am trying to install katoolin on Ubuntu 18.04 
I have done-

```
    git clone https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin.git
    sudo cp katoolin/katoolin.py /usr/bin/katoolin
    sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/katoolin
    sudo katoolin
```

When I run

```
sudo katoolin
```

it gives the following error-

```
File "/usr/bin/katoolin", line 8
    print "Sorry. This script requires sudo privledges"
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Sorry. This script requires sudo privledges")?
```

What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper Installation of Kali linux tools in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772495/proper-installation-of-kali-linux-tools-in-ubuntu) - Please read step 3. of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error and solution is located in the response.

1. Open katoolin.py in ATOM or your text editor of choice.
2. Change the line of code from `"Sorry. This script requires sudo privileges"` to `("Sorry. This script requires sudo privileges")`
3. Save the document.

There will be other errors since the latest Katoolin code was written in Python2. Python3 has some slight difference.

You can get by this by installing Python2 on your ubuntu installation and use it to run katoolin.

Comment: I have written a quick description about the fix here: https://4siteadvantage.com/linux/katoolin-for-ubuntu-19-10/