# Katoolin3 install in ubuntu 22.04.3LTS "Unable to correct problems you have held broken packages."

Tags: 22.04, katoolin, kali-linux-tools

I am joining a cybersecurity society at university and they require me to install katoolin3, I have ran it and selected to "install all" but it comes up with this error:

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVAGQ.png)

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

PS: I am running this in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper Installation of Kali linux tools in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772495/proper-installation-of-kali-linux-tools-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Katoolin breaks Ubuntu, and has for over a decade. Your cybersecurity society violated the first rule of computer *safety* if they truly gave you such dangerous instructions. Better to install Kali in a Virtual Machine.

Comment: To be very fair I was the one that wanted to do it on my own machine and not in a VM, I didn't know it completely broke it... How do I fix this now then?

Comment: You fix it by backing up your data and then reinstalling Ubuntu. Two hours to backup, reinstall, and restore is a cheap lesson learned. Alternately, you can dig deep into the katoolin scripts to undo the changes file by file. Folks tell me that takes a few days; I have never tried it.

Comment: In what way does it break it?

Comment: Because I haven't downloaded any tools, and there is an unninstall.sh file... And any GPG keys I have added I can remove...

Comment: "In what way does it break it?" Look at the output in your screen shot.

Comment: if you are successful at uninstalling Katoolin and restoring a working, healthy Ubuntu system, then please return and write an answer detailing your process.

Comment: All I did was cd katoolin3/ then sudo ./unninstall.sh removed the katoolin3 folder, and remove the GPG key I had added to be able to run the ./install.sh in the first place. My system seems to be working fine.I installed kali in a VM like you suggested.
I was searching it up and I am pretty sure it only breaks it if you install packages (at least in katoolin3), because they replace some original ubuntu packages, but because I had the luck of not even being able to install them in the first place it looks like everything is still fine. I just hope my PC doesn't blow up in the next few hours...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)